# SQL parameters from keyboard

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can somebody help how to enter a value of the parameters from the keyboard?

Example:

```
Declare @StartDate Date
Declare @EndDate Date

Set @EndDate = '2020-04-28';
Set @StartDate = '2020-01-01';

Select AT.AssetID as DHM, Sum(AT.AmountMST)*-1 as RocniOdpis
from ASSETTRANS as AT
where AT.DATAAREAID='tam' and AT.TRANSTYPE=3
  and AT.TransDate<@EndDate and AT.TransDate>@StartDate
Group by AT.ASSETID
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I would bracket AT.TransDate<@EndDate and AT.TransDate>@StartDate

Comment: If I get this correctly you might create a `MyParams` table, place the values there and use them in your queries.

Comment: Short answer is you can't - at least not with tsql. TSQL does not interact with a user and has no functionality to allow for prompting or for reading keyboard input. Perhaps some fancy Excel programming can do that. Otherwise, you (or someone else) needs to write a simple application for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather cryptic question, but what I think you are talking about is creating a stored procedure with parameters.  So you would have:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetMyData @StartDate Date, @EndDate Date
AS

SELECT  AT.AssetID as DHM, 
        Sum(AT.AmountMST)*-1 as RocniOdpis
FROM ASSETTRANS as AT
    WHERE AT.DATAAREAID='tam' 
            AND AT.TRANSTYPE=3
            AND AT.TransDate < @EndDate and AT.TransDate > @StartDate
Group by AT.ASSETID
```

And you would call it from the "keyboard" as such:

```
EXEC GetMyData '2020-04-28', '2020-01-01'
```

Comment: Thanks for your repply, but stored procedure does not solve my issue. I need something like message box with possibility to enter the date values there. I do not want to write the values into the code.

Comment: If you right click on that procedure in SSMS and select Execute Stored Procedure it will bring up a dialog that you can enter the dates you want. Not sure if that gets you closer or not to what you want

Comment: This query was created for users without sql knowledges and the goal is to run that through the excel query. That is why I need some messagebox where I can enter the values.